# Php rotate url from array

Tags: php, arrays, url, rotation

Say you have a file that contains an array with a time and a code like this:

```
{"TIME":"0410","ARRIVAL":"AAA"}
{"TIME":"0600","ARRIVAL":"BBB"}
{"TIME":"0600","ARRIVAL":"CCC"}
{"TIME":"0600","ARRIVAL":"DDD"}
```

I need to create something that rotates the url using the code from the array based on the time. The time function is no problem but how would I be changing(rotating) the url of a page with the codes from the array?

Comment: I dont understand the question. What do you mean by "*rotates the url using the code from the array based on the time*"? When asking questions, please do not assume that we know the context. Instead, make it explicit.

Comment: How do you want the result to look like ? That would make it easier to understand what exactly you mean with rotate. Also I don't see the correlation between your array and an url ?!

Comment: For instance there is a function checktime and it checks if the actual time is 2hours or less to the time in our array. If so then we want to use the code into an url

example:

the actual time is 03.00 and the first record in the array is 04.10 this is 2 hours or less so we want to create some url http://www.dummyurl.org/phpscript.php?show=AAA and 1 minute (or 30 second or whatever) change the url to http://www.dummyurl.org/phpscript.php?show=BBB if checktime is true. Hope this explains what i mean

Comment: Not really. Probably you should add the code to your question so it's more clear at which part you run into your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to know how to redirect the user to different urls.
You can either do that with JavaScript:

```
window.location = 'http://www.dummyurl.org/phpscript.php?show<?php echo $array[$now];?>
```

or the same with standard html redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; url=http://www.dummyurl.org/phpscript.php?show=<?php echo $array[$now];?>">
```

The `content=30` in the latter example means that it refreshes the page after 30 seconds to re-execute your check-function and change the URL appropriately.

Assuming you already built that checking function for the time difference, just put this code where it is appropriate!

To iterate through the different values on page load you can use `[array_search()][1]` and increase the array-key on the output!

```
$key = array_search($_GET['show'],$array);
if($array[$key+1]) { $loadme = $array[$key+1];}
else { $loadme = $array[0]; }
```

That way you search for the value in the URL, which returns you the key of the array it is in. Then you increase the key by one. If this key doesn't exist, it'll start on the first position again.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; url=http://www.dummyurl.org/phpscript.php?show=<?php echo $loadme;?>">
```

Comment: That would indeed change the url but only once, how would i do it so that it changes every 10 seconds to another url? Say array [$now] contains 3 codes AAA BBB CCC. The first 10 seconds it shows 'http://www.dummyurl.org/phpscript.php?show=AAA then 10 seconds later http://www.dummyurl.org/phpscript.php?show=BBB And so on. Actually it's a bit like an image rotator what I want but it doesn't rotate images but url's. These urls based on the array codes and timestamps.

Comment: change the `content=30` to 10. let your script detect the value in the url and change the url of the meta-refresh to the next value in the array! quite easy when using numeric arrays. please accept the answer if you're happy with it :)

Comment: That is indeed what i needed to know. How would i change to the next value in the array. Would be great if you could provide some insight on that one too :D

Comment: Thank you very much sir, much appreciated! No idea why this was closed. Seems like you where the only one who understood what I meant danontheline :D

Comment: I know it's not very easy to explain a problem when you are deeply in it. But when you ask a question always assume the reader knows nothing (apart from programming knowledge for sure). Being a teacher myself, I had to learn that too...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5276/discussion-between-logistef-and-danontheline)